# optional args in scipy.optimize

Tags: python, numpy

I am a bit stuck attempting to send optional arguments to scipy.optimize.minimize

```
def optimize_stuff(k):
    f = stub2
    init=np.array(3)
    x_min = scipy.optimize.minimize(f,init,args=(k),tol=0.1)

def stub2(x,y=3):
    return x*y**2
```

This gives

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple

I've tried every combination of parens and the like that i can think of to no avail; the docs on minimize seem (to me) indicate that the above should be ok.  The error thrown will probably make the solution obvious to someone with more python-fu than I...

Answer (score 1):

In the `minimize` call, you have tried to define the args as a tuple, but a tuple of one element should be defined like `args=(k,)`.

Comment: `np.array(3)` is a numpy array.  It's shape is `()`, ndim is `0`.  `np.array([3])` is 1d with `(1,)`.  Looks like `minimize` is happy with either.  Even plain `3` works.

Comment: args=(k,) fixed it, thanks.  would it be fair to call this a minor bug and report it somewhere or should i have known somehow ?

Comment: It's not a bug - `minimize` expects the args to be passed in some sort of array. The syntax for a tuple of size one might seem strange, but it is correct. It might seem less strange if you used a list instead, like `args=[k]`